# Swagger returns an unexpected HTML code response when endpoint is called

Tags: typescript, express, swagger, response, jsdoc

I was setting up ExpressJS backend for my project when this issue occurred. An endpoint on Swagger UI localhost returned a pure HTML upon clicking **Try it out** and **Execute**.

For this project I have been using this library: [express-jsdoc-swagger](https://github.com/brikev/express-jsdoc-swagger) and followed their guidelines/examples that were listed.

Thus far, nobody reported a similar issue so I suspect there is a mistake in my config file. Any help is **heavily appreciated**! My bet is there is something wrong with the pathing of the files but I have already tried changing it every way possible.

**Expected result:**

```
{
  foo: 'bar'
}
```

**Unexpected result:** [image: Weird HTML response]

Folder structure (without `package.json`, `node_modules` etc.):

```
src
 ┣ closure
 ┃ ┣ closure.routes.ts
 ┃ ┣ closure.ts
 ┃ ┗ index.ts
 ┣ common
 ┣ config.ts
 ┗ server.ts
```

My `config.ts`:

```
const swaggerOptions = {
  info: {
    version: '1.0.0',
    title: 'A tool',
    description: 'no description',
    license: {
      name: 'MIT license.',
      url: 'https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT',
    },
  },
  servers: [
    {
      url: 'http://localhost:3000',
      description: 'Development server',
    },
  ],
  baseDir: './',
  filesPattern: 'src/**/*.ts',
  swaggerUIPath: '/',
  exposeSwaggerUI: true,
  notRequiredAsNullable: true,
  swaggerUiOptions: {},
};
export default swaggerOptions;
```

My main file `server.ts`:

```
import express from 'express';
import swaggerOptions from './config';

const expressJSDocSwagger = require('express-jsdoc-swagger');

export const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

expressJSDocSwagger(app)(swaggerOptions);

app.listen(PORT);
```

And file where API is supposed to be called `closure.routes.ts`:

```
import { app } from '../server';

/**
 * GET /test
 * @summary This is the summary of the endpoint
 * @return {object} 200 - Success
 * @return {object} 400 - Bad request
 */
app.get('/test', (req, resp) => {
  resp.send({ foo: 'bar' });
});
```